# Google Map with two routes overlayed on top of each other

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map that I want to put a planned route and a traveled route on using the Google Maps Route API.

What I am doing is getting the legs of the planned route and adding those to the map. The route color is gray for that. Then I add the traveled route which is usually on top of the planned route. That route color is blue. I set the opacity of the planned route to 1 and the traveled route to .75.

Sometimes when the page loads, the planned route is on top and sometimes the traveled route is. I guess it's fetching the data from Google and it doesn't come back in order because of the nature of Javascript.

What I am looking for is to always make the planned route load before the traveled. My plan is to listen for an event and use a promise.

What events should I listen for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only event available on the [DirectionsRenderer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRenderer) is directions_changed:

> **Events**
>
> **directions_changed** | Arguments:  None
>
> This event is fired when the rendered directions change, either when a new DirectionsResult is set or when the user finishes dragging a change to the directions path.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rajy2jay/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var directionsService;
var directionsDisplays = [];

function initMap() {
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 7,
    center: {
      lat: 41.85,
      lng: -87.65
    }
  });
  var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  directionsDisplays.push(directionsDisplay);
  calculateAndDisplayRoute("New York, NY", "Los Angeles, CA", {
    strokeWeight: 8,
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeColor: "white"
  }, true);
  // directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(directionsDisplays[0], 'directions_changed', function() {
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    directionsDisplays.push(directionsDisplay);
    calculateAndDisplayRoute("New York, NY", "Denville,NJ", {
      strokeWeight: 4,
      strokeOpacity: 0.5,
      strokeColor: "blue"
    }, false);
  });

}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(start, end, options, preserveViewport) {
  directionsService.route({
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING'
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      directionsDisplays[directionsDisplays.length - 1].setOptions({
        map: map,
        polylineOptions: options,
        preserveViewport: preserveViewport
      });
      directionsDisplays[directionsDisplays.length - 1].setDirections(response);
    } else {
      window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```